# Update SQL but only on fridays

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

In a database I have two columns, one with `DATE` and another with `HOUR`, where I have to look in the `HOUR` column for a time interval and change. And also look for every Friday and put also in a specific `HOUR` but nothing is working.

This is the code to search for the `HOUR` and change, and is already working:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Clockings] set [Hour] = DATEADD(second,
   (ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 900), '07:45:00.000') where [Hour] > 
   '04:00:00.000' and [Hour] < '07:45:00.000'

UPDATE [dbo].[Clockings] set [Hour] = DATEADD(second, 
   (ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 900), '17:30:00.000') where [Hour] > 
   '17:45:00.000' and [Hour] < '23:59:59.000'
```

To search the `DATE` table nothing worked.

[image]

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (Some non-ANSI SQL there...)

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Perhaps some sample data will help

Comment: just to put all fridays in the same time. this is for a timereport in the company, all employes leve at 17.30 all days but on fridays the leave the company at 17.00, and i must put all emploeys leve at 17.00

Comment: If the day of the week (based on `date` field) is a Friday, then set the `hour` field to a specific time?

Comment: show us some expoected result plz

Comment: And the time is stored in `HOUR` field (with `datetime` datatype) as an offset from `'1899-12-30'` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server) 2012 or later:

```
Update Clockings
    Set ...
    Where DatePart(dw, [Date]) = 5; --Friday
```

Note, check which day is the first day of the week. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms181598.aspx

`DateName()` function may also suit.

Comment: 1251 rows affected